# Is there a plugin like Compressor for Craft 3?

Tags: craft3

Is there are similar plugin for Craft 3 like https://github.com/sathoro/Compressor?

Comment: I think most people are doing this type of thing via a build step, via webpack, Gulp, Mix, Grunt, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a single plugin, but looking through https://plugins.craftcms.com it looks like maybe [Minify](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-minify) and [Asset Rev](https://github.com/clubstudioltd/craft-asset-rev) would do it together.